# The only proper subfield of $\mathbb C$ , which is path connected as a subset of $\mathbb C$ , must be $\mathbb R$?

Tags: field-theory, path-connected

Is it true that the only proper subfield of $\mathbb C$ , which is path connected as a subset of $\mathbb C$ , must be $\mathbb R$ ?

NOTE : The answer to this [Subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ which are connected with induced topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831654/subfields-of-mathbbc-which-are-connected-with-induced-topology)  indicates the claim stated is true . But the answer there only gives a reference and no proof ( or outline of proof) of the result , and the paper cited is highly technical . I would like to see if there is any elementary ( at least more elementary than the cited paper if possible ) proof .

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1831998/110831) says that the answer is yes, and gives a reference for a proof.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon : please see my edit

Comment: Do you have any evidence that one can be *less* technical about it? (As for the answer in the older question containing no proof… it is not a sensible requirement for people to type proofs here, specially when they are long and, well, technical, if they are available, no?)